# Why do engines compress the air-fuel mixture prior to combustion?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, combustion

In a basic Otto-cycle internal combustion engine, the air-fuel mixture that is drawn into the cylinder is compressed prior to the spark plug initiating the combustion process. **Why is is beneficial to compress the air prior to combustion?** Combustion, from a chemical perspective, can take place at ambient pressures. What is "better" about compressing the air-fuel mixture prior to combustion?

Does it change the energy released by the chemical reaction? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Suddenly compressing the fuel/air charge causes its temperature to go up. This helps volatize the fuel droplets before ignition, thus getting a better burn with less smoke. It also increases the temperature at which heat is being added during the Otto cycle, increasing the difference between ambient and the combustion temperature which increases the Carnot efficiency of the cycle.